# Leaflet.js - Tilelayer visible above geojson layer. GeoJSON interactivity issue

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I have a leaflet.js project where I have a baselayer, a polygon geojson layer, and another tilelayer **above** the geojson layer which shows placenames. I've managed to get the placenames tilelayer to visualise above the geojson layer by adding it to a map pane. However, this has disabled click and hover events on the geojson layer. I'm thinking I probably have to add the goejson layer to it's own pane, or possibly the same pane as the placenames tilelayer, but I'm not sure.

Here's my code which add my placenames layer to a pane:

```
var topPane = map.createPane('leaflet-top-pane', map.getPanes().mapPane);
    topPane.appendChild(CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels.getContainer());
```

Here's my CSS code for the pane:

```
    .leaflet-top-pane {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I've tried adding my geojson layer to the same pane, and changing the pointer-events option, but either it won't work, or I haven't hit on the right combination. Has anyone any ideas as to how I can resolve this so that I can have my tilelayer overlay above my geojson layer but still be able to interact with the geojson layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the Leaflet library properly (e.g. manually appending a layer to a HTML container), assuming you will know the CSS class of the pane, etc).

Use this instead:

```
map.createPane('labels');    
map.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 1000;
map.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

var positron = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
    pane: 'labels'
}).addTo(map);
```

You can see a [working example here](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/yek/edit?html,output).

Comment: Hi IvanSanchez. Thanks for your help. That worked. Only issue I have is my on click polygon layer popups are appearing below the positron placename layer. I need them to appear above the placenames. Is this something I can change using the zIndex?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to have a look at the [values for the z-indexes of the default panes](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/dist/leaflet.css#L71) - so the labels appear on top of the overlays (geojson & vectors) and markers, but under the popups.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the link. I set the 'labels' pane zIndex to 600 and it's working perfectly. Cheers Ivan.